# update one table with 2 where conditions in the same and one condition in another table

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have 2 tables **fees** and **students**. i want to update one field of fees with 3 **WHERE** conditions, i.e, 2 conditions in table 'fees' and 1 condition in table 'students'.

I tried many queries like

```
UPDATE fees, students SET fees.dues= 300 WHERE fees.month= November 
AND fees.session= 2017-18 AND students.class= Nursery
```

It gives me error like `java.sql.SQLException: near",": syntax error`

I am using sqlite as database. Please suggest me a query or let me correct this query.

Thanks

Comment: How are the `fee` and the `students` table related?

Comment: the primary key of students is used as foreign key in fees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot join tables in a UPDATE command in SQLite. Therefore, use a sub-query in the where condition

```
UPDATE fees
SET dues = 300
WHERE
    month = November AND
    session = 2017-18 AND
    student_id IN (SELECT id FROM students WHERE class=Nursery)
```

Also, I am not sure about the types of your columns. String literals must be enclosed in single quotes ('). The expression `2017-18` would yield the number 2017 minus 18 = 1999. Should it be a string literal as well?

```
UPDATE fees
SET dues = 300
WHERE
    month = 'November' AND
    session = '2017-18' AND
    student_id IN (SELECT id FROM students WHERE class='Nursery')
```

Comment: i made it done with your second query :) , it worked for me thank you so much... May the creator put both of us on the right path :)